# In c++ do you have 'out parameters' like in c#?

Tags: c++

In c++ do you have 'out parameters' like in c#?

In c# the method signature would be:

```
bool TryGetValue(int key, out OrderType order)
```

The idea is the variable may not be assigned before passed but MUST be assigned before exiting the method.

MSDN out params link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645764(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: You can always initialise the variable and pass it as a reference.

Comment: Doesn't Boost have something to enforce this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing as strict as C# `out` parameters in C++.  You can use pointers and references to pass values back but there is no guarantee by the compiler that they are assigned to within the function.  They are much closer to C# `ref` than `out`

```
// Compiles just fine in C++
bool TryGetValue(int key, OrderType& order) {
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

No, there are no `out` parameters in C++ that force you to assign to it before exiting the function. Pointers and references are more like `ref` parameters in C#.

Answer (score 3):

If you really like a 'out' keyword, you can define a maro:

```
#define out
```

as a mark, although it has not effect for compiler.

Just like some one would define 'public', 'private' keyword for C.

Comment: Why downvote, it's a good suggestion, this dummy macro is much better describes the code than any comments around.

Answer (score 1):

You can use references or pointers to simulate out parameters, but a better way is to use tuples (`std::tuple` in C++11 or `boost::tuple` in C++98/03) to return multiple values from a function. You cannot return without a complete tuple.

```
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<bool, OrderType> TryGetValue(int key) {
    OrderType ot;
    ...
    return std::tuple<bool, OrderType>(true, ot);
}

...

bool b;
OrderType o;
std::tie(b, o) = TryGetValue(k);
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be one use of references:

```
bool TryGetValue(int key, OrderType &order)
```

Then you can simply assing to `order` and the calling function would get the data.